# How to display the Sindhi Language fonts?

Tags: java, android, fonts

I'm making an app in my native language Sindhi.

Note: Sindhi language has 52 alphabets, like this

```
**ا، ب، ج،ف، ڪ**
```

I have installed Sindhi fonts on my PC, also I have the unicodes of Sindhi.

**Problem**

When I set text on my Button, like this

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSindhiLessons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="سنڌي سبق"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
```

It shows perfectly on the code view but in design view it's showing something like this:

[image]

but on device or emulator it renders like this:

[image]

Notice that one letter is missing. I'm using Android 4.0.4

Comment: Does it render differently on a 4.4 emulator?

Comment: @orip I haven't tested this on 4.0.4, its not rendering correctly. I think it will render correctly in  4.2 + but not sure. I want to make this app run on android 2.3.3 and +

Answer (score 2):

It's because `Eclipse` doesn't support `Sindhi`. While in your device it may support of it's 4.0+, I'm not sure it'll look good if you have an early android device.

check [this](http://www.java-forums.org/eclipse/61445-my-eclipse-do-not-support-arabic-farsi-font.html) out.

Comment: Im using android 4.0.4

Comment: Yes that's why it's properly. But if you used older versions of android it won't be proper writings. You need to encode it. You can use this amazing reshaper. https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper

Comment: thanks for your answer. but Sindhi language has some more characters then the arabic. which is not supported also and fails to be rendered here in my device . what could be the solution of this,

Answer (score 1):

you are copy pasting the text directly to the code:

use uni code:

like this: `\u0623,\u0623,\u0623,\u0623` for your every character

```
or
```

get supportive type face,which support sindhi.

one i know that is **jameel noori nastaleek**

hope it will solve your issue

Comment: yes I have tried also with unicodes, but it miss my some characters to render

Comment: I downloaded and set fonts on my buttons text. but not usefull. it still misses some characters like ڌ .

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps :

- Find best font for Sindhi
- Place that font to your asset folder
- Set this font as typeface to your button